# Deploy Laravel using bitnami/latavel docker image

Tags: laravel, docker, bitnami

I'm trying to deploy a Laravel app using bitnami/laravel docker image. When using docker-compose locally and mount a root dir to /app everything works as expected.

But when using my custom Dockerfile:

```
FROM bitnami/laravel:5.8.35
COPY . /app
```

My app gets overwritten by the default app. I guess the "FROM" image gets executed after my COPY command and overwrite the app.

What is the best practise to use custom image like this?

**Seems like my configuration in Azure caused this issue**

Comment: Did you declare your app as a volume? You can't just randomly mount files and folders on your host machine into containers.

Comment: By using the docker-compose file in the bitnami repo you can see it mount a volume to /app. https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-laravel/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

But when using a custom Dockerfile and copy the file into the location, they will be overwritten by the default app.

Comment: Hmm so I see. That's interesting. Does `COPY ./ /app` work?

Comment: Can you access the container with `docker run -ti your-custom-image bash` and list the files under `/app`? The container only creates a new app if there's no `/app/config/database.php` file (ref: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-laravel/blob/master/6/debian-9/rootfs/app-entrypoint.sh#L44), so it's possible that your files aren't being correctly copied. If I had to venture, I would say your `database.php` is ending in a place like `/app/somedir/config/database.php`

Comment: Can you post the complete Dockerfile?
Where you are trying to deploy your image?